# Find the intersection points of all the line segments

Tags: algorithm, line-intersection

Given a list of line segments, the easiest way to find the intersection points is to loop through the line segment list, check whether they are intersecting and record the intersection point if they do.

But the runtime of this method is `O(n^2)`, which is very inefficient. Is there any other algorithm that could speed up this process?

Comment: Maybe if there was a way you could sort them...? Hmm good question!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The [Bentley-Ottmann Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bentley%E2%80%93Ottmann_algorithm) may be what you are looking for.

Comment: Ah, that's *the* answer I've been looking for.