# Find lines crossings algorithm

Tags: algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find the Intersection Points of All the Line Segments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125452/find-the-intersection-points-of-all-the-line-segments)

Hi,

I have a set of lines defined by 2 points. Could you please recommend me a fast algorithm which finds all the crossings?

Thanks

Comment: _Lines_ or _line-segments_? Probably the latter, but one never knows...

Answer (score 3):

In case you mean line-segments, you can use the [Bentley-Ottmann algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bentley%E2%80%93Ottmann_algorithm) which finds all crossings in `O((n+k)*log(n))` where `k` is the total numer of crossings and `n` is the number of segments in your set.

Comment: just to add, there was a question regarding implementation on SO before, maybe it helps: Sibilance, definition, "ouch!" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407493/existing-bentley-ottmann-algorithm-implementation